# Force value in javascript csv formatted string to be text

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, excel, csv

I'm grabbing the info from a jquery datatable and creating a csv formatted string with javascript and then posting the string to a C# web service api call to create a file that can be downloaded.  I'm posting to the web service instead of creating the file for download directly in javascript because IE doesn't like to do that.  The issue I'm having is I have a column that can contain alphanumeric or just numeric values.  When the numeric values are extremely long, they are converted to scientific notation when opening in Excel.

```
                    for (var row = 0; row < $rep_data.length; row++) {
                    //$str_return += '<tr>';
                    detail = '';
                    for (var col = 0; col < self.dataColumns.length; col++) {
                        //omit select/checkbox column and wtb image column
                        if (col != 0 && col != 1) {
                            if ($rep_data[row][self.dataColumns[col].data] == null)
                                detail += ',';
                            else {
                                var re = /^(-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[0-1]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(\.[0-9]+)?(Z|[+-](?:2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):[0-5][0-9])?$/;
                                if ($rep_data[row][self.dataColumns[col].data].match(re)) {
                                    var formatedDT = moment($rep_data[row][self.dataColumns[col].data]);
                                    detail += '"' + moment(formatedDT).format('M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss A') + '",';
                                }
                                else {
                                    var result = $rep_data[row][self.dataColumns[col].data].replace(/"/g, '""');
                                    result = '"' + result + '"';
                                    detail += result + ',';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    detail = detail.substring(0, detail.length - 1) + '\n';
                    $str_return += detail;
                }
```

I've seen some posts about prepending '=' to the value so it's treated as a forumla, but it doesn't appear to be working or I'm doing something incorrectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe there is anything that can be done outside of Excel to stop this behaviour. If there is, it's highly unlikely it's possible on a plaintext format like CSV.

Comment: This sounds very excel specific. It might be worth editing the question to reflect as much.

Comment: Not Excel specific, I'm formatting a javascript string like this:  " 15061614380011","NEW","CITY"," 1234","NW TEST ST E","PASS CHRISTIAN","MS 811 INC","6/16/2015 6:38:00 PM","N","AERATION CORE/LAWN","6/16/2015 2:38:00 PM"

When it reaches the C# code, it becomes this:  \"15061614380011\",\"NEW\",\"CITY\",\" 1234\",\"NW TEST ST E\",\"PASS CHRISTIAN\",\"MS 811 INC\",\"6/16/2015 6:38:00
 PM\",\"N\",\"AERATION CORE/LAWN\",\"6/16/2015 2:38:00 PM\"

I want to be able to format either one of these strings so it forces text.  I don't want the user to have to format the column manually within Excel.

Comment: @user3379395 "The issue I'm having is I have a column that can contain alphanumeric or just numeric values. When the numeric values are extremely long, they are converted to scientific notation when opening in Excel." sounds excel specific. That is not a javascript question.

Answer (score 1):

Decided to create a simple csv file using a text editor and after some trial and error was able to get the numbers formatted properly by using "=".  I wasn't doing it correctly when I first tried to use it.

```
                                var re = /^(-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[0-1]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(\.[0-9]+)?(Z|[+-](?:2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):[0-5][0-9])?$/;
                                if ($rep_data[row][self.dataColumns[col].data].match(re)) {
                                    var formatedDT = moment($rep_data[row][self.dataColumns[col].data]);
                                    detail += '="' + moment(formatedDT).format('M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss A') + '",';
                                }
                                else {
                                    var result = $rep_data[row][self.dataColumns[col].data].replace(/"/g, '""');
                                    if (isNumeric(result))
                                        result = '="' + result + '"';
                                    else
                                        result = '"' + result + '"';
                                    detail += result + ',';
                                }
```

Put in this function to check for "isNumeric":
    function isNumeric(n) {
                    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
                }